# Integrating $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x(\sin x)^6}{(\sin x)^6+ (\cos x)^6}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

Can't really wrap my head around this integral. I tried doing some u-subs, but it just doesn't get much easier. Would really appreciate any help.

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x(\sin x)^6}{(\sin x)^6+ (\cos x)^6}\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Even though the duplicate uses the exponent $2018$, the accepted answer works with any even exponent, including the $6$ present here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!